# GWT 2.5 compilation error

Tags: gwt

If client side code changes we can refresh the page to recompile it and see the results. It worked nice with GWT 2.4

As of GWT 2.5 there is a problem. Upon page refreshing a `com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException` is thrown. 
If I restart the web application and refresh the page everything goes fine. So it seems to be some bug in GWT.

A few details:

1. This exception is thrown if anything is changed, for example css file (!)
2. This exception is thrown often but not always, sometimes it is OK.
3. Actual exception may concern almost any class. In this example it is java.lang.Integer.

> com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IncompatibleRemoteServiceException: The
>   response could not be deserialized    at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:221)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:287)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:395)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:338)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:219)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:571)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:279)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
>     at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)    at
>   com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:242)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find class
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.lang.Integer_FieldSerializer
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase.getTypeHandler(SerializerBase.java:164)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase.instantiate(SerializerBase.java:114)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.ClientSerializationStreamReader.deserialize(ClientSerializationStreamReader.java:396)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamReader.readObject(AbstractSerializationStreamReader.java:119)
>     at
>   ru.minogin.data.shared.model.BaseEntity_FieldSerializer.deserialize(BaseEntity_FieldSerializer.java:29)
>     at
>   ru.minogin.data.shared.model.OrderedEntity_FieldSerializer.deserialize(OrderedEntity_FieldSerializer.java:22)
>     at
>   ru.pickbook.shared.model.Format_FieldSerializer.deserialize(Format_FieldSerializer.java:133)
>     at
>   ru.pickbook.shared.model.Format_FieldSerializer.deserial(Format_FieldSerializer.java:163)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase.deserialize(SerializerBase.java:95)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.ClientSerializationStreamReader.deserialize(ClientSerializationStreamReader.java:398)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamReader.readObject(AbstractSerializationStreamReader.java:119)
>     at
>   ru.pickbook.shared.model.Album_FieldSerializer.deserialize(Album_FieldSerializer.java:105)
>     at
>   ru.pickbook.shared.model.Album_FieldSerializer.deserial(Album_FieldSerializer.java:141)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase.deserialize(SerializerBase.java:95)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.ClientSerializationStreamReader.deserialize(ClientSerializationStreamReader.java:398)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamReader.readObject(AbstractSerializationStreamReader.java:119)
>     at
>   ru.pickbook.shared.model.OrderItem_FieldSerializer.deserialize(OrderItem_FieldSerializer.java:48)
>     at
>   ru.pickbook.shared.model.OrderItem_FieldSerializer.deserial(OrderItem_FieldSerializer.java:75)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase.deserialize(SerializerBase.java:95)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.ClientSerializationStreamReader.deserialize(ClientSerializationStreamReader.java:398)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamReader.readObject(AbstractSerializationStreamReader.java:119)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.Collection_CustomFieldSerializerBase.deserialize(Collection_CustomFieldSerializerBase.java:34)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.HashSet_CustomFieldSerializer.deserialize(HashSet_CustomFieldSerializer.java:34)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.HashSet_FieldSerializer.deserial(HashSet_FieldSerializer.java:19)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase.deserialize(SerializerBase.java:95)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.ClientSerializationStreamReader.deserialize(ClientSerializationStreamReader.java:398)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamReader.readObject(AbstractSerializationStreamReader.java:119)
>     at
>   ru.pickbook.shared.model.Order_FieldSerializer.deserialize(Order_FieldSerializer.java:152)
>     at
>   ru.pickbook.shared.model.Order_FieldSerializer.deserial(Order_FieldSerializer.java:196)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase.deserialize(SerializerBase.java:95)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.ClientSerializationStreamReader.deserialize(ClientSerializationStreamReader.java:398)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamReader.readObject(AbstractSerializationStreamReader.java:119)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter$ResponseReader$8.read(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:106)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:214)
>     ... 28 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find
>   class
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.lang.Integer_FieldSerializer
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.ReflectionHelper.loadClass(ReflectionHelper.java:93)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase.getTypeHandler(SerializerBase.java:160)
>     ... 61 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.CompilingClassLoader$MultiParentClassLoader.findClass(CompilingClassLoader.java:368)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.CompilingClassLoader$MultiParentClassLoader.loadClass(CompilingClassLoader.java:388)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.ReflectionHelper.loadClass(ReflectionHelper.java:91)
>     ... 62 more

Comment: FYI, problem already reported here https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-web-toolkit/LE_TSOkGpVk/discussion but no one replied. I don't use RPC so I can't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
-Dgwt.disableGeneratorResultCaching
```

Answer (score 0):

The bug is not in the GWT framework, but in the browser plugins. It shouldn't happen in production mode.

If possible, switch to SuperDev Mode, you will get rid of the exceptions.

Comment: SuperDev Mode is not ideal, since you have to debug in the browser (most of us use an IDE for a reason).

Comment: You can debug from the IDE, just can't modify variable values.